# Regex Javascript How To Imitate Negative Lookbehind from PHP Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex `(?<!#)hazcon\s?0` and my sample test messages. The trouble I am having is converting this to Javascript from PHP since Javascript does not support negative lookbehind. I would like to match for any `hazcon 0` or `hazcon0` but ignoring any instances of `#hazcon0` and `#hazcon 0`.

`#hazcon0` <- don't match this

`#hazcon 0` <- don't match this

`hazcon 0`

`hazcon 0`

`blah blah blah blah hazcon0 blah blah`

`blah blah blah blah hazcon 0 blah blah`

If there is a better way to do this I would like to understand!

Comment: Reverse your sample message and do a negative lookahead: `reversedStr = str.split('').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of requiring there not to be an octothorp, require that there is the beginning (`^`) or a character other than an octothorp (`[^#]`)

```
(^|[^#])hazcon\s?0
```

Comment: This approach won't work if anyone needs to replace consecutive double `"` that is not preceded with `"`.This solution will only work with the strings like those in the original question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that shouldn't require lookbehind. Though I'm not sure if you mean a quote cannot immediately precede the double consecutive quotes (`replace(/(^|[^"])""/g, '$1')`) or it cannot precede it at all  (`replace(/^([^"]*)""/g, '$1')`)

Comment: As I said, [it does not work](https://regex101.com/r/dU6iZ4/1) because the consecutive `""`s are preceded with `"`. This solution you provided is *context dependent*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, then I must not understand what you are attempting. That regex replaced two consecutive quotes that were not preceded by a quote.

Answer (score 0):

Reversed string approach can fail in specific situations (like when you need to match consecutive double apostrophes not before an opening bracket). The most reliable way to use a negative lookbehind is using `XRegExp` library with some [*extensions*](https://gist.github.com/slevithan/2387872).

```js
// Simulating infinite-length leading lookbehind in JavaScript. Uses XRegExp.
// Captures within lookbehind are not included in match results. Lazy
// repetition in lookbehind may lead to unexpected results.

(function (XRegExp) {

    function prepareLb(lb) {
        // Allow mode modifier before lookbehind
        var parts = /^((?:\(\?[\w$]+\))?)\(\?<([=!])([\s\S]*)\)$/.exec(lb);
        return {
            // $(?!\s) allows use of (?m) in lookbehind
            lb: XRegExp(parts ? parts[1] + "(?:" + parts[3] + ")$(?!\\s)" : lb),
            // Positive or negative lookbehind. Use positive if no lookbehind group
            type: parts ? parts[2] === "=" : !parts
        };
    }

    XRegExp.execLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        var pos = 0, match, leftContext;
        lb = prepareLb(lb);
        while (match = XRegExp.exec(str, regex, pos)) {
            leftContext = str.slice(0, match.index);
            if (lb.type === lb.lb.test(leftContext)) {
                return match;
            }
            pos = match.index + 1;
        }
        return null;
    };

    XRegExp.testLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        return !!XRegExp.execLb(str, lb, regex);
    };

    XRegExp.searchLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        var match = XRegExp.execLb(str, lb, regex);
        return match ? match.index : -1;
    };

    XRegExp.matchAllLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        var matches = [], pos = 0, match, leftContext;
        lb = prepareLb(lb);
        while (match = XRegExp.exec(str, regex, pos)) {
            leftContext = str.slice(0, match.index);
            if (lb.type === lb.lb.test(leftContext)) {
                matches.push(match[0]);
                pos = match.index + (match[0].length || 1);
            } else {
                pos = match.index + 1;
            }
        }
        return matches;
    };

    XRegExp.replaceLb = function (str, lb, regex, replacement) {
        var output = "", pos = 0, lastEnd = 0, match, leftContext;
        lb = prepareLb(lb);
        while (match = XRegExp.exec(str, regex, pos)) {
            leftContext = str.slice(0, match.index);
            if (lb.type === lb.lb.test(leftContext)) {
                // Doesn't work correctly if lookahead in regex looks outside of the match
                output += str.slice(lastEnd, match.index) + XRegExp.replace(match[0], regex, replacement);
                lastEnd = match.index + match[0].length;
                if (!regex.global) {
                    break;
                }
                pos = match.index + (match[0].length || 1);
            } else {
                pos = match.index + 1;
            }
        }
        return output + str.slice(lastEnd);
    };

}(XRegExp));

// DEMO
document.body.innerHTML = "hazcon 0: " + XRegExp.testLb("hazcon 0", "(?<!#)", XRegExp("\\bhazcon\\s*0\\b"));
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>hazcon0: " + XRegExp.testLb("hazcon0", "(?<!#)", XRegExp("\\bhazcon\\s*0\\b"));
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>#hazcon0: " + XRegExp.testLb("#hazcon0", "(?<!#)", XRegExp("\\bhazcon\\s*0\\b"));
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>#hazcon 0: " + XRegExp.testLb("#hazcon 0", "(?<!#)", XRegExp("\\bhazcon\\s*0\\b"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

See [*JavaScript Regex Lookbehind Redux*](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind):

> That's less than 0.5 KB after minification and gzipping. It provides a collection of functions that make it simple to emulate leading lookbehind:
>   
>       `XRegExp.execLb`
>       `XRegExp.testLb`
>       `XRegExp.searchLb`
>       `XRegExp.matchAllLb`
>       `XRegExp.replaceLb`